# Determine if the set is compact

Tags: real-analysis

$$S=\{1,1/2, 2/3,3/4,....\}$$
I think this is compact as it has one sequence that covers all elements in set except $1$. This sequence is $a_n=\frac n{n+1}$. This sequence converges to $1$ hence all subsequences in $S$ converge to $1$, which is in $S$. Also this is bounded in $[1/2, 1]$.

Comment: Your reasoning is right: the space is sequentially compact, and hence compact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this set is compact by Heine-Borel. It is closed (contains its limit point) and it is bounded.

Answer (score 4):

Directly from the definition of compactness:

Let be $(V_i)_{i\in I}$ an open cover of $S$. Let be $i_0$ s.t. $1\in V_{i_0}$.

As $n/(n+1)\to 1$, $\exists n_0\in\Bbb N$ s.t. $n\ge n_0\implies n/(n+1)\in V_{i_0}$.

Finally, for each $n < n_0$ take $i_n$ s. t. $n/(n+1)\in V_{i_n}$.

The family $\{V_{i_0}, V_{i_1},\dots,V_{i_{n_0-1}}\}$ is a finite open subcover of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$1$.  A set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$  is said to be compact iff it is closed and bounded .

$2$. If $D(A)\subseteq A$ , then $A$ is closed.

NOTE: For given set $S$ , it's all terms lie between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$.